# Как сделать уведомление в телеграм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, flask, redis

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Имею веб приложение Flask и телеграм-бота. Суть вот в чем:

1. Пользователь делает заказ через форму. жмет отправить.
2. Заказ сохраняется в redis
3. Телеграм-бот должен отправить *мне* (подчеркиваю, с ботом буду взаимодействовать только я) информацию о заказе.

**Вопрос**: Как лучше настроить взаимодействие, чтоб телеграм бот сразу уведомлял меня о заказе? Бьюсь целый день и никак не могу найти простого решения

Спасибо!

Comment: а в чем именно у вас трудность? Вы не знаете как отправить сообщение? Или как выстроить алгоритмическую последовательность действий? Не совсем понятно из вопроса

Comment: я не знаю как настроить взаимодействие между ботом и веб-приложением. я не знаю как вызывать метод отправки у бота который запущен в другом процессе в нужный чат нужному пользователю. по сути мне нужно оформить взаимодействием между ботом и веб приложением для решения моего вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно в работающем процессе телеграмма раз в минуту заного получать данные из redis. Скорее всего бот в данном случае работает через long pooling. Гораздо удобнее работать через веб хуки.
У меня свой бот, сделал его для уведомлений. Все работает через django. Создаю сигнал с данными, слушатель получает и отсылает сообщение.

Comment: слушай, а можешь подробнее и более конкретно описать?

Comment: Создал сайт на django. Пара таблиц для хранения сообщений. Записи проектов (название, домен или ip, описание), к каждому проекту можно добавлять записи (логи). Лог состоит из названия, поля для traceback (text), тип (info, warning, error, debug), дата и привязка к прокту. Клиент добавляет запись через rest api. Перед добавлением получает токен. В самой django, при добавлении новой записи создаю сигнал. Функция которая прослушивает данный сигнал вызывает мой класс и метод отправки. Бот работает через web hook, для этого пришлось поставить ssl сертификат на домен.

Comment: Что конкретно интересует? Так в нескольких предложениях трудно описать даже часть функционала.